# It is possible for user refresh webpage and redirect to another url?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I'm building a site wordpress and i want to redirect to a page
when user refresh, redirect home of my site.
It is possible? 
this code can be right?

```
$(window).unload(function()
{
    var reload = confirm("are you sure you want to leave?");
    if(reload)
    {
        location.reload(); // Refresh the site, not needed really.
        location.href = "http://example.com"; // Redirect.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code working atleat for me

```
       <body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">
        //modify your body tag

       myFunction(){
         event. preventDefault(); //for Mozilla browser only
        document.location.href="/";  //Redirect to your home
                                                               page 
       }
```

Comment: Now i try,the problem is that I do not know where to put it.
My site is gamesrad.altervista.org and the page gamesrad.altervista.org/premisettimanali/ is the page that if refresh 
must return to the home.
Where files i insert this?

Comment: I understand your requirement.Here your home page(landing page) URL   is gamesrad. altervista. org and the URL of  page your try to refresh is gamesrad.altervista.org/premisettimanali/ .

Comment: Yes but i don't know where i insert your code.
I'm not very good with javascript and I do not know where to put your code to make everything work.

Comment: Hey dude I modified  initial code I posted. Now I modify it for your readability

Comment: Thank you,if you are good in javascript can help me? I have other problem javascript with ajax page load.
If you go in this page: http://gamesrad.altervista.org/palinsesto/
There is schedule and working but i use ajax page load and i want go in this page through my menu,schedule DISAPPEAR.
You can see this problem,going to: gamesrad.altervista.org,open left menu and click on ''Palinsesto''
Any solution?

Comment: I m also not well in English so please clear your requirement. I can't identify whats your issue now?.. If u clearly show your issue.. I will help you to solve this issue dude